How to convert wide-data to long-data format for big dataset?
I am conducting a cross-sectional online study about 54 illnesses, and have 10 variables/columns for participants' background information, then participants were randomly assigned to a set of 9 different illnesses (for each illness I had 20 questions, with the beginning of the columnname signifiying the kind of illness : epi_fam, epi_exp..; ms_fam, ms_exp., autism_fam, autism_exp etc.).
I am trying to convert the data from wide to long format in an efficient way, so that I have a new column indicating the kind of illness, but I am not sure how to do that.
Does someone have an idea ?
Thanks in advance!
L
I tried it using pivotlonger function of tidyr but I do not manage the thing with the illness column names.

Please use minimal reproducible examples others can run using copy & paste. Show desired output entirely. Use dput() for data & specify all non-base packages with library(). Don't embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

You can use the pivot_longer function from the tidyr package. I used three columns (id, age, and sex) as background information and two types of illnesses as samples. Please keep in mind that the order of values for the names_to argument is determined by the pattern of variable names in the data (whether the illnesses are before "_" or after), and I assume they are before the separator.
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 5, 1),
                 age = c(29, 32, 45, 75, 39),
                 sex = c("m", "f", "m","m", "f"),
                 epi_fam = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                 epi_exp = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 ms_fam = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                 ms_exp = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0))

df
#>   id age sex epi_fam epi_exp ms_fam ms_exp
#> 1  1  29   m       1       1      0      1
#> 2  2  32   f       0       1      0      1
#> 3  3  45   m       0       0      1      1
#> 4  4  75   m       1       0      1      0
#> 5  5  39   f       1       1      0      0

idcols <- names(df[,1:3])

pivot_longer(data = df,
             cols = -c(all_of(idcols)), 
             names_to = c("illness", ".value"),
             names_sep = "_") 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 6
#>       id   age sex   illness   fam   exp
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1    29 m     epi         1     1
#>  2     1    29 m     ms          0     1
#>  3     2    32 f     epi         0     1
#>  4     2    32 f     ms          0     1
#>  5     3    45 m     epi         0     0
#>  6     3    45 m     ms          1     1
#>  7     4    75 m     epi         1     0
#>  8     4    75 m     ms          1     0
#>  9     5    39 f     epi         1     1
#> 10     5    39 f     ms          0     0

Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks a lot that was super helpful and worked :D ! One last question, how can I add the number of observation/participant to this ? Thanks a lot really!

You're welcome! If you're referring to the number of participants per illness, then you can use a dplyr package like this.df |> group_by(illness) |> mutate(n_obs = n()) |> ungroup()
